# Aluminum Hydroxide electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry

Does molten Aluminum Hydroxide break up to aluminum, water, and oxygen by electrolysis? It's easy to write the equation $$\ce{4Al(OH)3 -> 4Al + 6H2O + O2}$$ but is this actually possible?

Comment: Just look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93H%C3%A9roult_process) in wikipedia. The aluminum hydroxide would dehydrate to produce alumina, which is used in the H-H process.

Comment: Why would alumina be formed instead of splitting into aluminum and hydroxide ions? If this was done in air then I understand but in an inert atmosphere? If the hydroxide ions interact then water would form and the excess oxygen could react with the aluminum

Comment: Look at the equation you have in your question: it is not balanced. Two aluminum hydroxides, when heated sufficiently, lose three water molecules and form alumina, i.e., $\ce{Al2O3}$. This is exactly what happens on a large scale as an intermediate step in the production of aluminum via the H-H process. It has nothing to do with the atmosphere. It is simply the reaction that actually happens. This is quite common. For example, magnesium hydroxide, when heated sufficiently, loses water and magnesia, i.e., MgO, is produced.